# How to extract a very big file in Google Colab

Tags: google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

I am trying to extract a 14.6 GB 7z file (https://archive.org/download/stackexchange/stackoverflow.com-Posts.7z).

I have it downloaded and saved in my Google Drive. I mount my drive to Google Colab and then change the current directory to where the file is located: `os.chdir('/content/drive/My Drive/.../')`

When I try to unzip the file `!p7zip -k -d stackoverflow.com-Posts.7z`, it uses the current instance's HDD space and during this process, it runs out of all the available allocated HDD space, and hence the unzip abruptly terminates.

Is there a way to extract the file without using the instance's HDD space OR do it in chunks, such that the extract is successful.

PS: I believe, when decompressed the file size is ~100 GB

Answer (score 1):

You can try to read data by blocks, using libarchive, without unzip it first.

https://github.com/dsoprea/PyEasyArchive

Here's an [example notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/10xCvcd8OZri0yF2F_hpV8iJ0IA7hp6Au)

Comment: Umm, could you please provide more information? There is just one file zipped inside the 7z, and I do wish to unzip it. It is an XML, and I wish to process it later using python... without running into an out of space error of course.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I have a doubt; I have been reading these XMLs like `tree = ET.parse('data/english.stackexchange.com/Users.xml')`, `root = tree.getroot()` and then iterate for children in root (`for child in root:    user = child.attrib`). Do you know if I can do something similar?
From the code that you wrote, it seems like I can read it in chunks... but I was hoping to extract the whole thing and read it as an XML itself.

Comment: You need to change from 7z to gz. Then you can do that. You can read 7z by block, then compress to a new gz. After finish creating gz, then gzip.open it, and send to iterparse.